# Biopython PDBIO assembly chain IDs

Tags: biopython, pdb

I am using Bio.PDB to parse structures in mmCIF and PDB format. I realised that PDBIO does not deal well with two-character chain identifiers (like ‘AA’ or ‘AB’) found in **assembly** structures. I have made a slight change to the code that fits me. Attached you will find the modified PDBIO module. What it does basically is checking the length of the chain identifier string and adds a space in front of it, if is a single character. The formatting string is modified accordingly.

These are my changes in Bio.PDB.PDBIO module. Please consider it putting it in a future update.

**Modified:**

`_ATOM_FORMAT_STRING = "%s%5i %-4s%c%3s%s%4i%c   %8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%s%6.2f      %4s%2s%2s\n"`

**Modified:**

```
for chain in model.get_list():
    if not select.accept_chain(chain):
        continue
    chain_id = chain.get_id()
    if len(chain_id)==1:                  #Added line
        chain_id = ' {}'.format(chain_id) #Added line
```

**Modified:**

`fp.write("TER   %5i      %3s %s%4i%c                                                      \n`

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is a site to ask questions. What you are proposing is a change to BioPython software. Luckily, BioPython is open-source, so you create a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) so that your change can be added to the software.

- Go to https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/PDB/PDBIO.py
- Click on the arrow icon in the top right corner. This will create a [fork](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-forks) of the BioPython repository

  [image: screenshot]
- Make the changes that you mentioned above in your fork and a title and a description:

  [image: screenshot]
- Click on `propose file change`. You can now visually compare your modifications side by side.

  [image: screenshot]
- If everything looks OK, click on `create pull request`. This will send a pull request to the master branch of the BioPython repository. There it will be reviewed. If the authors of the BioPython software agree that this is a usefull change, they will merge it into the sofware.

  [image: screenshot]